# Put returned value of js function on specific position within page

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress, eval

I got this code that puts an ad on my Wordpress blog:

```
<script src="http://www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js">
googletag.pubads().definePassback('xxx', [320, 250]).display();
</script>
```

Because I want to insert this halfway my posts/articles I use this line of javascript to put it in the right position:

```
$('.entry-content h2:nth-of-type(3)').before('Ad here');
```

This works fine, but how do I insert the script here? I tried to load the gpt.js file somewhere else and replaced 'Ad here' with:

```
googletag.pubads().definePassback('xxx', [320, 250]).display();
```

and tried to do that with and without the eval() function, but can't get it to work.

Do I need to use eval(), AJAX or some other technique?

update: Tried to put

```
<script>googletag.pubads().definePassback('xxx', [320, 250]).display();</script>
```

at the bottom of the page and move it onload to the right place. It ended up on the right spot, but didn't display the ad.

Comment: Can't figure it out. Managed to make it work with a Wordpress filter on the_content. Would love to know if it's possible this way though.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code

```
$('.entry-content h2:nth-of-type(3)').before($("<script />", {
    html: "googletag.pubads().definePassback('xxx', [320, 250]).display();"
}));
```